Remove the offset at the ends of TikZ double line and use exact coordinates
TikZ double line does not start and end the line exactly at the given coordinates. It adds double line thickness as shown in the first figure below.
Is there a way to remove the offsets at the ends of the line, and draw the line exactly at the given coordinates as shown in the second figure below?
The MWE:
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [line width=0.4cm, color=gray, double distance=1cm, line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (5,0);

\draw [] (-0.5,0) --  ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (0,0) -- node[at start, anchor=west]{$(0,0)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (5,0) -- node[at start, anchor=east]{$(0,5)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (5.5,0) --  ++(0,-1.5cm);

\draw [<->] (-0.5,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {0.5} ++(0.5,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {5} ++(5,0);
\draw [<->] (5.5,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {0.5} ++(-0.5,0);

\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]

\draw [line width=0.4cm, color=gray, double distance=1cm, line cap=rect] (0.7,0) -- (4.3,0);

\draw [] (0,0) -- node[at start, anchor=west]{$(0,0)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (5,0) -- node[at start, anchor=east]{$(0,5)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);

\draw [<->] (0,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {5} ++(5,0);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I selected thick line width so that its effect on the figure can be seen more clearly.


Why you end lines with line cap=rect?

@Zarko : I add line cap option so that I can close the ends. Adding lines to the ends manually becomes hassle for some paths.

You could shorten the line by half of the double distance +  half of the line width:
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [line width=0.4cm, color=gray, double distance=1cm, line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (5,0);

\draw [] (-0.5,0) --  ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (0,0) -- node[at start, anchor=west]{$(0,0)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (5,0) -- node[at start, anchor=east]{$(0,5)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (5.5,0) --  ++(0,-1.5cm);

\draw [<->] (-0.5,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {0.5} ++(0.5,0);
\draw [<->] (0,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {5} ++(5,0);
\draw [<->] (5.5,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {0.5} ++(-0.5,0);

\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]

\draw [line width=0.4cm, color=gray, double distance=1cm, line cap=rect,shorten <=0.7cm,shorten >=0.7cm] (0,0) -- (5,0);

\draw [] (0,0) -- node[at start, anchor=west]{$(0,0)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\draw [] (5,0) -- node[at start, anchor=east]{$(0,5)$} ++(0,-1.5cm);

\draw [<->] (0,-1.25cm) -- node[below] {5} ++(5,0);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks. I was not aware of the shorten option.

@berkus You're welcome!
